# JavaScript regex to replace a whole word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable:

```
var str = "@devtest11 @devtest1";
```

I use this way to replace `@devtest1` with another string:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('@devtest1', 'g'), "aaaa")
```

However, its result (`aaaa1 aaaa`) is not what I expect. The expected result is: `@devtest11 aaaa`. I just want to replace the whole word `@devtest1`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `\b` zero-width word-boundary assertion.

```
var str = "@devtest11 @devtest1";
str.replace(/@devtest1\b/g, "aaaa");
// => @devtest11 aaaa
```

If you need to also prevent matching the cases like `hello@devtest1`, you can do this:

```
var str = "@devtest1 @devtest11 @devtest1 hello@devtest1";
str.replace(/( |^)@devtest1\b/g, "$1aaaa");
// => @devtest11 aaaa
```

Comment: \b is a bit tricky with the start though, imagine the input of: `"!!@devtest1"` and a pattern of `/\b@devtest1\b/`. There is no word-boundary between "!" and "@". (That is, the definition of word boundary is specific; but not always appropriate.)

Comment: Show what you tried. (As @user2864740 says, it won't work on the start; but then that is not what the example in the question had trouble with.)

Comment: @user2864740 So how can I do it?

Comment: "not successfully" is an useless bug report. If you have a failing test case, please report it, and what happens instead.

Comment: that would also match `hello@devtest1` which is not what op would expect

Comment: @Anirudha oh, you're right. hello@devtest1 will match

Comment: @Anirudha, yes, it would. As I said, if that is a failing case, OP should mention it. For example, in UNIX, `a b$cd e` is reading variable `$cd`, and `a`, `b` and `e` are separate tokens, and this is the correct behaviour for this case. I prefer not to solve problems that do not need solving.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary `\b` for limiting the search to words.

Because `@` is special character, you need to match it outside of the word.

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`, since `\b` does not include special characters.

```js
var str = "@devtest11 @devtest1";
str = str.replace(/@devtest1\b/g, "aaaa");

document.write(str);
```

If your string always starts with `@` and you don't want other characters to match

```js
var str = "@devtest11 @devtest1";
str = str.replace(/(\s*)@devtest1\b/g, "$1aaaa");
//                 ^^^^^                ^^

document.write(str);
```

Comment: `\b` between `@` and `devtest1` is useless, as it will always match (the neighbours being constant).

Comment: `@\bd` is a bit useless; it is equivalent to `@d`. Putting a `\b` before `@` is also problematic .. but it can be omitted for the sown data.

Comment: that would also match `hello@devtest1`

Comment: @Anirudha Check the other solution, now it wont

Comment: @Anirudha Kindly check again. I've updated answer not to remove spaces. Thanks for pointing out mistake

Comment: @Tushar thanks for your update. Your second solution is what I expect ^^

Comment: the new edit will also match `@devtest1#`.. blame it on `\b`.. ;-)

Comment: Optional spaces will match `hello@devtest1` again :)

Comment: @Anirudha: To me, that's a word boundary. If not, again, I blame it on OP's vague problem definition (using "whole word" imprecisely, when `@devtest11` is not already a word)

Answer (score 1):

`\b` won't work properly if the words are surrounded by non space characters..I suggest the below method

```
var output=str.replace('(\s|^)@devtest1(?=\s|$)','$1aaaa');
```